# In Shadows Over Camelot, when does a knight die if his life points drop to zero on another player's turn?

Tags: shadows-over-camelot

Rules as written, p. 12, emphasis mine:

> If your Life points fall to zero (as a result of this voluntary sacrifice, or at any other point during the game, regardless of the reason for it), you die and disappear from the game at the end of **your** game turn.

Suppose I have one life point remaining. The player to my left begins their turn and plays a black Morgan card, "Each Knight immediately loses 1 Life Point." Barring being saved by the Grail, what happens? Am I immediately dead and out of the game? Or does play go all the way around the table back to me, where I can take a full turn at zero life points, and then die at the end of *my* turn? The latter seems to be what the rules indicate, but that seems rather... wrong... for this otherwise unforgiving game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in fact, this is a translation error in the English rules of the game.

The "at the end of your turn" part should be removed from this sentence. When you fall down to 0 Life points, you're dead immediately unless you drink from the Grail...

Here is a forum thread where Bruno Cathala brings light on the issue:
https://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?th=4531

As you say, this game is unforgiving and whenever in doubt, you're pretty safe to choose the worst option ;-)